# Assign "type" to Lightning Button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Is it possible to assign a type value to a Lightning button? For example, `type="submit`?

```
<lightning:button variant="base" label="Base" title="Base action" />
```

I have a submit button in a form, and default behavior for `type="submit"` is the form can be submitted on keyboard Enter. Can I add the `type` attribute to the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

From [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:button/specification):

> Specifies the type of button. Valid values are button, reset, and submit. This value defaults to button.